# change operator from minus to plus and vice versa in calculator app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, calculator

this is my first question about a calculator, bear with me. I have to do a button to reverse the plus minus operator. So 1+2-3 would become 1-2+3.
I managed a simple string like 1+2 into 1-2 and vice versa with a btnChangeOperator. However when I tried to 1+2-3 and want to change that to 1-2+3, it got me 1+2+3 and then to 1-2-3.
I tried first with regular expression:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("[+-]");
if (txtInput1.Text.Contains("-"))
{ 
    txtInput1.Text = pattern.Replace(txtInput1.Text, "--");//jace can manage that, I also tried "+" 
    txtInput2.Text = pattern.Replace(txtInput2.Text, "+");
}
else if (txtInput1.Text.Contains("+"))
{               
    txtInput1.Text = pattern.Replace(txtInput1.Text, "+-");//jace can manage that, I also tried with "-"
    txtInput2.Text = pattern.Replace(txtInput2.Text, "-");
}
```

That works only with 1+2 or 1-2 and 1+2+3 or 1-2-3 but not with 1+2-3 or 1-2+3. I also tried with Replace but it is the same problem:

```
if (txtInput1.Text.Contains("-"))
{
    txtInput1.Text = txtInput1.Text.Replace("-", "+");
    txtInput2.Text = txtInput2.Text.Replace("-", "+");
}
else if (txtInput1.Text.Contains("+"))
{
    txtInput1.Text = txtInput1.Text.Replace("+", "-");
    txtInput2.Text = txtInput2.Text.Replace("+", "-");
}
```

I tried also to change first into mathematical arithmetic like +-/-+=- and --=+ and than change the again to +/-. But that won't work as +- would change into +. I use the [Jace addition](https://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/jace-net-just-another-calculation-engine-for-net/) to calculate, which is really nice. I thought also about a switch case but I do not manage to implement that.
Can someone point me in the right direction as the difficulty is that plus can be minus but in my code it will change directly to plus again. 
Thank you.

edit:
I used Joe Phillips answer which is so simple and nice, no if statements but just 1 line of code (well 2 because I have 2 txtFields).

```
txtInput1.Text = txtInput1.Text.Replace("+", "p").Replace("-", "+").Replace("p", "-");
txtInput2.Text = txtInput2.Text.Replace("+", "p").Replace("-", "+").Replace("p", "-");
```

Thx all.

Comment: `string result = string.Concat(source.Select(c => c == '-' ? '+' : c == '+' ? '-' : c));`

Comment: If this isn't some kind of homework requiring the use of regexes, be aware that you're probably starting down the wrong route. You're trying to work with *expressions* and sooner or later you'll need to be lexing and parsing rather than just keeping things as strings. But it's a *vast* topic.

Comment: You can't change all +'s to -'s then change all -'s to +'s, for obvious reasons. Iterating through all characters, changing them if appropriate, and concatenating the result is how you have to do it. Like in the comment above.

Comment: You could be "clever" and just change the + and - to another symbol first, then do the replace. Like this: `Replace("+", "a").Replace("-", "+").Replace("a", "-")`

Comment: If it is a regex homework you'll have to convert all + to a non-numeric token, like DumbassAssignment, then flip -s to +, then replace all instances of that token with -s. <edit> uh, like the comment above.

Comment: Ik have 2 txtResuls, because my teacher want want in txtResult1 the input and then result in and txtResult2 the complete arithemethic like in txtResul1 1+2 and then when you press = txtresult1 is 3 and txtResult2 is 1+2=3

Comment: @JoePhillips that is a great idea! I will try that. @ Dmitry thx but I do not understand you solution.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It insn't a homework about regular expressions, it liked to be neat to me at the time. They want me to make al calculator who make also logs to a SQL database. I will make it happen ;)

Comment: [UCT+1] here to make me sleep.Thank you all for your responses. I will answer as soon as possible. Thanks for your great insights. Grateful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just changing a minus to a plus and visa versa, use regex replace with a match evaluator

```
var text = "001-34+323";

Regex.Replace(text, "[-+]", me => { return me.Value == "-" ? "+" : "-";   })
```

**Result**

```
001+34-323
```

---

If need be you can make the match evaluator consider more scenarios, just add more code in between the braces.

[Match Evaluator Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?view=netframework-4.7.2)